# How do I ignore the first option that the find method gives me?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have to scrape a page that records the date twice in a row with the same method. The first time it registers it only with the year, the second with the complete date.

I need how to scrape over the entire date, but the find method only shows me the first one (which doesn't interest me).

[image]

```
root_items = soup.find_all("div", class_="asset-full-content clearfix mb-5 no-title")

for root in root_items:
    response = root.find("input", class_="field form-control").get('value')
```

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Provide foucsed HTML example as text not as image and take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
dateLabel = "Fecha de publicación" #copy label text EXACTLY
response = root.find("label", string=dateLabel).findNext('input').get('value')
```

but you must make sure `dateLabel` is an **exact** match for the label text or use a suitable regex. Include input class in `findNext` if there might be more than one input tag after the label.

Or, if you know the (`index`), use `root.find_all(....)[index]` instead of just `find`